# Transfer serially into Arduino Uno, the text file read by Qt Creator

Tags: qt, arduino, serial-port, text-files, qt5

This is from my previous question of read the text line by line.

Based from @KubaOber answer, I can successfully read and display the content line by line in a certain time interval.

Then, I was trying to transmit the content of the text file serially into Arduino Uno using the source code available on the internet.

Here's the header code:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>

namespace Ui {

class Widget;


}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    QSerialPort *arduino;
    static const quint16 arduino_uno_vendor_id = 10755;
    static const quint16 arduino_uno_product_id = 67;
    QString arduino_port_name;
    bool arduino_is_available;
    QByteArray serialData;
    QString serialBuffer;

    void updateSpeedometer(QString);

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
     Ui::Widget *ui;
private slots:


private:




};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

and here's the main.cpp :

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include "widget.h"
#include <QDebug>

bool arduino_is_available = false;
QString arduino_port_name = "";

QSerialPort *arduino = new QSerialPort;
QString serialBuffer = "";

static const quint16 arduino_uno_vendor_id = 10755;
static const quint16 arduino_uno_product_id = 67;

class PeriodicReader : public QObject {

   Q_OBJECT


QTimer m_timer{this};
QFile m_file{this};
void readLine() {
  if (m_file.atEnd()) {
     m_timer.stop();
     return;
  }

  QByteArray lineBaru(m_file.readLine());

  emit newLine(lineBaru);
  qDebug()<<lineBaru;
  QString lineString(lineBaru);
  qDebug()<<lineString << " converted to QString";
  lineString.remove("\n");
  qDebug()<<lineString;
  lineString.remove(" ");
  qDebug()<<lineString;

  QRegExp rx("d(\\d+)");
  QList<int> list;
  int pos = 0;

  while ((pos = rx.indexIn(lineString, pos)) != -1) {
      list << rx.cap(1).toInt();
      pos += rx.matchedLength();
  }
  qDebug()<<list;
  int listi = list.at(0);
  qDebug()<<"list[0] :"<<listi;// <<---THIS IS WHERE I CAN GET THE VALUE AFTER THE "d"

  updateSpeedometer(lineString);

}

   void updateSpeedometer(QString command)
   {
       if(arduino->isWritable())

       {
           command.remove(" ");

           arduino->write(command.toStdString().c_str());

           qDebug() << command.toStdString().c_str() << " is uploaded to Arduino";

       }else{
           qDebug()<<"Couldn't write to Serial !" ;
       }
   }


public:
   explicit PeriodicReader(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &PeriodicReader::readLine);
   }
   void load(const QString & fileName) {
      m_file.close(); // allow re-opening of the file
      m_file.setFileName(fileName);
      if (m_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
         readLine();
         m_timer.start(1000); // <<<---------------HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE DELAY TO BE
      }
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void newLine(const QByteArray &);
};

QString lineToString(QByteArray line)
   {
   while (line.endsWith('\n') || line.endsWith('\r'))
      line.chop(1);
   return QString::fromUtf8(line);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    qDebug()<<"Number of available ports :" <<QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts().length();

      foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()){
                  qDebug()<<"Has Vendor ID:" << serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier();
                  if(serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier()){
                      qDebug()<<"Vendor ID:"<< serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier();
                  }
                      qDebug()<<"Has Product ID:" << serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier();
                      if(serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier()){
                          qDebug()<<"Product ID:"<< serialPortInfo.productIdentifier();
                      }
              }

              foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()){
                  if(serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier() && serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier()){
                      if(serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier() == arduino_uno_vendor_id){
                          if(serialPortInfo.productIdentifier() == arduino_uno_product_id){
                              arduino_port_name = serialPortInfo.portName();
                              arduino_is_available =  true;
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }

                  if(arduino_is_available){
                      //open and configure the serialport

                      arduino->setPortName(arduino_port_name);
                      arduino->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
                      arduino->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
                      arduino->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
                      arduino->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
                      arduino->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
                      arduino->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
                      //QObject::connect(arduino,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readSerial()));

                  }else{
                      //show error message
                      qDebug()<<" Port Error, Couldn't find the Arduino' !";

                   //   QMessageBox::warning(this, "Port Error, Couldn't find the Arduino !");
                  }

   QApplication app{argc, argv};

   QWidget window;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&window};
   QPushButton load{"Load"};
   QPlainTextEdit edit;
   layout.addWidget(&load);
   layout.addWidget(&edit);
   window.show();

   PeriodicReader reader;
   QObject::connect(&load, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
      auto name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(&window);
      if (!name.isEmpty()) {
         edit.clear(); // allow re-opening of the file
         reader.load(name);
      }
   });
   QObject::connect(&reader, &PeriodicReader::newLine, &edit,
                    [&](const QByteArray & line){ edit.appendPlainText(lineToString(line)); });

   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

It is from the coding of "reading text line by line" I've asked months a go which I include the arduino serial connection coding as well  and hey, it worked!

It reads the text line by line and when each line is displayed in textEdit, it also transmitted to Arduino Uno.

So my request is, instead of the delay between line by line  is preset at 2 seconds, can the delay duration be controlled by the content of the text file?

Let say.. the first line content inside the text file is **'s200 d300'** , and the **'s200'** is processed by arduino to generate a frequency, meanwhile **'d300'** is the delay interval in milliseconds before it reads the next line and generate another frequency signal.

So,how to make Qt recognise the **'d300'** and use it as the delay value?

Comment: use `QString str = "asdfsed d300 dfv0";
  QTextDocument  document(str);
  QTextCursor d =  document.find("d300");
  qDebug()<<d.position();`

Comment: Or you can find << d >> then gradually take turns to check the numbers after << d >>  until the end of the line

Comment: @Programmer_ARM I have found the ways to get the value after the <<d>> , but when I assign the value after <<d>> as an int for the delay function, qt reads it as value "0" , instead of "300" based on the above example.
 
`QRegExp rx("d(\\d+)");
QList<int> list;
int pos = 0;
while((pos=rx.indexIn(lineString, pos)) != -1) { \\lineString is a string where "s200 d300" is kept 
list << rx.cap(1).toInt();
pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
qDebug()<<list;
 int listi=list.at(0);
 qDebug()<<"list[0] :"<<listi; // displays "list[0] :300"`

Comment: A in the string can be several <<d>> characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString str = "asa24fsesfd300kslfv0";
QTextDocument  document(str);
QTextCursor d =  document.find("d");
qDebug()<<d.position();
QString s = str.mid(d.position()-1,6); // How many digits can be after << d >>
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    QString d = s.at(i);
    if(d.isEmpty()){
        break;
    }else{
        bool ok;
        int k = d.toInt(&ok);
        if(ok){
            count++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
}

QString result  = str.mid(d.position(),count);
bool ok;
int result_int = result.toInt(&ok);
if(ok){
    qDebug()<< result_int;
}
```

---

```
result 300
```

Comment: I have already able to retrieve the value of "300" from the "d300", the problem is when I include it inside a delay function, which is the "m_timer.start(<<here is where I want the value to be included>>);" , the delay does not follow according to the value.

Comment: `#include <windows.h>...
Sleep(uint(ms));`

Comment: Thank you, sir. I have found the solution, which is relocate the `m_timer` location after calling the function of `updateSpeedometer(lineString);`

Thank you for your assist!